# Connection refusal when pushing to Heroku, Bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ssh, railstutorial.org

I have had no issue pushing to Heroku or Bitbucket over the past few weeks. Now whenever I issue the command $ **git push** , or $ **git push heroku** I receive the same message:

> ssh: connect to host git.bitbucket.org port 22: Connection refused
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I have been using the cloud9 IDE, pushing to BitBucket with no issue, and am really at my wits end in trying to determing why  I can't push anymore....

Any advice out there?

Comment: Note, I also get a connection refusal when trying to run: bundle upate. I think there is an some authentication issue that I can't quite work out.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't authorized your computer's SSH key. You'll need to log into Heroku / bitbucket and make sure that your local ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file is appropriately copied over.

For Heroku, if you're using their command line tool, you can add your SSH keys easily:

```
$ heroku keys:add
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem.  I had to restart the C9 server and things worked fine after that.